# How to use item id from v-for list in a method of underlying component in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, v-for

I have a vue template that contains a component that is nested in a v-for list.
This component has a onSave method and on save I want to update that item in the backend db.
I'm having issues accessing the item id in that onSave function. The component's onSave function cannot accept inputs unfortunately.
Any pointers on how I can get that item.id or index?

```
<div v-for="(item,index) of items" :key="index">
 <span>{{ item.id }}</span>
 <Component v-model="item.text" :componentId=generateRandomString() @onSave="onSave"/>
</div> 

<script>
  import {Component} from 'component'
  import apiService from '../service/apiService'

  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadItems() {
      try {
        const r = await apiService.getItems();
        this.items = r.data;
      }
      catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    },
    onSave() {
      //Here I try to get the item.id or the item.index to find which item I need to update
    },
    generateRandomString() {
      return randomString();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the item and the index to onSave, you can then access any properties in the item:

```
<Component v-model="item.text" :componentId=generateRandomString() @onSave="(v, h) => onSave(v, h, item, index)"/>

...

    onSave(v, h, item, index) {
      //Here I try to get the item.id or the item.index to find which item I need to update
    },
```

Comment: As stated in the question "The component's onSave function cannot accept inputs unfortunately". So I cannot pass the item or the index in that function unfortunately

Comment: @Francois why it cannot accept params? it can accept params event without params in its signature, i've fixed the code

Comment: most likely the question was not specific enough. the component is md-editor-v3 that has this @onSave function: `(v: string, h: Promise<string>) => void`. So if I pass params, then that function does not do the intended operation.

Comment: @Francois you are mistaken with onSave calling your callback function and calling your function inside the callback manually. i've added params back.